# Strings from index in array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

If I have an array of strings:

```
array1 = ['mango', 'orange', 'apple','strawberry'];
```

and one array of indexes:

```
array2 = [1,3];
```

How can I create a new array with the strings in array1, based on the indexes in array2?

The new array would in this case look like this:

```
array3 = [orange, strawberry]
```

Comment: Iterate the array of indexes and use the value of those to index the first array and push those values into a new array, see answer/

Comment: Map array2 with array1.  Try that and add an attempt to your question.

Comment: It’s a simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `const array3 = array2.map((index) => array1[index])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare a new array object
let newArray = [];

//iterate the array of index values, and use the value to index the first array and push into new array
for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    newArray.push(array1[array2[i]]);
}

//log the results in new array
console.log(newArray);
```